# jquery mobile and chrome : loading pages

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I'm actually having some HTML pages using jQuery Mobile framework and my question is simple : on Chrome, how can i open a page from another ?

```
<a href="page2.html"> Go to page2 </a>
```

My goal is to apply transition effects so i added for example :

```
data-transition="turn"
```

but my browser gave me this error :

```
Error loading page : XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/.../page2.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Running Chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files option didn't fix my problem. I tried to add : 
    `rel="external"`
but it canceled all animation between my pages.

Can you see an issue for resolve this problem ?

Comment: This should work normally on Chrome with no issues. Anyway, try this `$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { transition: 'flip' });`

Answer (score 1):

Download xampp. Install it and place your folder with jqm files(my_jqm_folder) inside the httpdocs file.
Open xampp and run Apache server.
(Be carefull, you have to close your skype first, because they use the same port by default. After you run Apache run your skype again tere ll be no prob.)
Then go to chrome and type: localhost/my_jqm_folder/my_html_file.html

Answer (score 0):

Add rel="external"
`<a href="page2.html" rel="external"> Go to page2 </a>`